About F.Lawvere article "AN ELEMENTARY THEORY OF THE CATEGORY OF SETS"
reference articles:
[L] AN ELEMENTARY THEORY OF THE CATEGORY OF SETS (LONG VERSION) WITH COMMENTARY, F. WILLIAM LAWVERE (http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/11/tr11.pdf)
[T]  Topos theory, P.Johnstone (1977).
..............
In the article [L], Lawvere define a category (let name) L-Set  using categorical axioms.
Essentially it's a boolean topos where the final object is a generator and is  irreducible (has only trivial subobject), Lawvere assume the a categorial chose-axiom too.
By the way I observe (T.5.39  of [T]) that if we assume chose-axioms for the (underground sets topos) $Set$,  then L-Set has the categorical chose-axiom too,  I wondered why Lawvere don't avoid chose-axiom, for try to make  L-Set without chose axiom?
Anyway I tried to read the article avoiding any assumption of set theory or concept of that, therefore I barred in my vocabulary things as: the large (or narrow) "set of objects of the category", nor the "set of morphisms" between two objects, nor concepts such as "subset of morphisms with a certain property among those of a certain set of morphisms" ecc. I have just objects,  an element of an object $A$ is a (mono)morphism of the type $a: 1\to A$, thus objects conveys the idea of set as collection of elements, the (usual) idea of subset is conveyed by the concept of monomorphism.
Then Lawvere explain the Natural-object axioms: a object  $\mathbb{N}_L$ with  $o: 1\to \mathbb{N}_L,\ s: \mathbb{N}_L\to \mathbb{N}_L$ and the universal property   respect any data $x: 1\to X,\ f: X\to X$.
I ask how we can use [L] for make a (what we can mean easy) simple sequent of objects like:
$$1,\ A,\ A\times A,\ A\times A\times A,\ \ldots$$
where go to a place to the next just multiplying for $A$ ?
I know the we can define the "finite cardinal" $[x]$ (object of L-Set) from a morphism $x: 1\to \mathbb{N}_L$ (called element on $\mathbb{N}_L$), and we have (sse [T]) that $[o]\cong 0$ (initial object), $[s\circ x]=[x]\sqcup 1$, for example  $1=[s\circ o],\ 1\sqcup1=[s\circ s\circ o],\ldots $ and and so on for  some finite steps, then $A\times A\cong A^{1\sqcup1},\ A\times A\times A \cong A^{1\sqcup1\sqcup1}$ make by a direct finite construction, but I haven't (inside the contest o the article) the usual Peano axioms of set's for define the entire sequence.
Intuitively: is any $: 1\to N$ obtained as $0\to N\xrightarrow{s}N\xrightarrow{s}N\xrightarrow{s}\ldots \xrightarrow{s}N$ for a "enough" repetitions of $s $?
The usual Peano axioms resolve this requirement (physical, intuitive, philosophical,  natural?): the subset of the reachable elements (in the sense just given) is the entire set of natural elements.
I observe that If we suppose:
"set theory" (with $\mathbb{N}$  and Peano natural induction, and formation of set's form a property (separation axiom)).
And suppose on L-Set the operation of (countable) union of subobjects (enough with domain $1$).
Then:  $s^n\circ o: 1\to \mathbb{N}_L,\ n\in \mathbb{N}$ are all the points of $\mathbb{N}_L$, indeed:
let $\mathbb{N}'_L\subset \mathbb{N}_L$ the union of such points,  then $s$ as a factorization $s: \mathbb{N}'_L\to \mathbb{N}'_L$ indded:  let $P$ the pullback of $\mathbb{N}'_L\subset \mathbb{N}_L$ and $\mathbb{N}'_L\subset \mathbb{N}_L\xrightarrow{s} \mathbb{N}_L$ then each point $x: \to \mathbb{N}'_L$ is lifted by  the regular monomorphism  $P\to \mathbb{N}'_L$, then $P\to \mathbb{N}'_L$ is a epimorphism, then a isomorphism. Then by the universal property there is a section of  $\mathbb{N}'_L\subset \mathbb{N}_L$ then $\mathbb{N}'_L= \mathbb{N}_L$.
Therefore if set theory is assumed a prori (as an accessory to the metalogic with which we build the theory of the article) then what has been done in the article is equivalent to the category of sets (that is premised). But if we do not start with set theory, I seem we find difficulties just for the elementary constructions easly allowed by set-theoretic principle of induction.

A sequence of elements of $X$ is a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$.  You want a sequence mapping $0 \mapsto 1$, $1 \mapsto A$, $2 \mapsto A\times A, ..., k \mapsto A^k$.  Before you do this you must specify the codomain of this function $f$!  Once you have that it will be easy to use the universal property to construct $f$.

"Lawvere define a category (let name) L-Set using categorical axioms" No, Lawvere does not define any category. He presents axioms, ETCS, which may be satisfied in many different categories. "I observe (T.5.39 of [T]) that if we assume chose-axioms for the (underground sets topos) , then L-Set has the categorical chose-axiom too." No, even if we assume that $\mathsf{Set}$ satisfies the axiom of choice, ETCS minus choice will have models which violate the axiom of choice (Lawvere gives an example in Remark 2 on p. 16 of the document you linked to).

"I wondered why Lawvere don't avoid chose-axiom, for try to make L-Set without chose axiom?" I don't know Lawvere's philosophical views on the axiom of choice, but I can speculate that he viewed the axiom of choice as a fundamental property satisfied by the category of sets. As described in his introduction to the ETCS paper, the work developed out of the goal of providing set-theoretic foundations for an undergraduate analysis class he was teaching. Choice is, of course, indispensable for the basics of real analysis.
